# 'RenderBox was not laid out' when using ExpansionPanelList

Tags: flutter

I want to show a GridView on the left and a ExpansionPanelList on the right. I put them in a Row Widget but it did not work, error is :

```
Assertion failed:
D:\…\rendering\box.dart:1929
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#bb5e9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT"

The relevant error-causing widget was
Row
lib\main.dart:69
```

this is all my code in main.dart:

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp(UniqueKey()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp(Key key) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(UniqueKey()),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage(Key key) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

List<int> getDataList() {
  List<int> list = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < 96; i++) {
    list.add(i);
  }
  return list;
}

List<Widget> getWidgetList() {
  return getDataList().map((item) => getItemContainer(item)).toList();
}

var i = 0;
Widget getItemContainer(int item) {
  return Block(item);
}

//创建gridview
Widget buildGrid() {
  return GridView.count(
    //水平子Widget之间间距
    crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    //垂直子Widget之间间距
    mainAxisSpacing: 30.0,
    //GridView内边距
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    //一行的Widget数量
    crossAxisCount: 4,
    //子Widget宽高比例
    childAspectRatio: 2.0,
    //子Widget列表
    children: getWidgetList(),
  );
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("this is title"),
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: buildGrid(),
          ),
          ExpansionPanelPage(UniqueKey()),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}

class Block extends StatelessWidget {
  final int itemNo;

  const Block(this.itemNo, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerHover: (event) => print(itemNo.toString()),
      onPointerMove: (event) => print("aa" + itemNo.toString()),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          "item",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
        ),
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}

// stores ExpansionPanel state information

class Item {
  Item({
    required this.expandedValue,
    required this.headerValue,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });

  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
  bool isExpanded;
}

List<Item> generateItems(int numberOfItems) {
  return List.generate(numberOfItems, (int index) {
    return Item(
      headerValue: 'Panel $index',
      expandedValue: 'This is item number $index',
    );
  });
}

class ExpansionPanelPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ExpansionPanelPage(Key key) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExpansionPanelPageState createState() => _ExpansionPanelPageState();
}

class _ExpansionPanelPageState extends State<ExpansionPanelPage> {
  List<Item> _data = generateItems(1);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          width: 10,
          height: 10,
          child: _buildPanel(),
        ),

    );
  }

  Widget _buildPanel() {

      return ExpansionPanelList(
        
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _data[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: _data.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
        return ExpansionPanelRadio(
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(item.headerValue),
            );
          },
          body: Column(
            children :<Widget>[
              Text("1"),
              Text("1"),
              Text("1"),
              Text("1"),
            ]
          ),
          value: item.headerValue,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

..........................................................................
..........................................................................

Comment: Add this line inside Listview.count `shrinkwrap:true` hope it's helpful to you

Answer (score 3):

I know it might be a bit late to answer your question but for those who are facing the same issue, try wrapping **ExpansionPanelList** with the **SingleChildScrollView** widget. It helps your panel list to take all available space and to shrink-wrap in both axes. Check the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) for more info!

Comment: Worked. Actually [the official example of `ExpansionPanelList`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html) uses this solution.